# Arrange Images in a grid-like fashion on monitor as well as mobile devices using <div>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a set of images that I want to arrange in a grid-like fashion. I want 6 per row on a full-width monitor, but for smaller screens (tabs/smartphones) the pics should arrange themselves. I've tried the following code:

```
<div style="width: 120px; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 40px; position: relative;">

[caption id="" align="alignnone" width="110"]<a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img class="size-full wp-image-76" alt="ALT Text" src="ImageSource.jpg" width="110" height="110" /></a> Image Caption[/caption]

</div>
```

I repeat this code for every image and for every sixth  tag I use margin-right: 0px and after the sixth `<div>` tag I have to use `<br>` to bring the other images to the next row on the full-width monitor.

The problem is that on tabs/smartphones only one image is displayed even if there is enough space for two more. The next images move down. And the sixth and seventh images get stick to each other without any space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unordered list as a container, not a DIV. (assumed photo width of 100px)

```
ul, li (margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}    
ul {max-width: 600px;}
li {float-left; width:100px;}
```

Adjust for margins accordingly